Hessenberg matrix and Householder transformations
Let $A$ be a real unreduced upper Hessenberg matrix of order $n$.
a)Show that A can be factored into A=QR, where R is upper triangular matrix and $Q=H_{1}H_{2}\ldots H_{n-1}$ orthogonal with each $H_{k}$ being a Householder matrix.$H_{k}=I-2w^{k}(w^{k})^{T}$ $1\leq k\leq(n-1)$
b)Show that orthogonal matrix Q in the previous part is an upper Hessenberg matrix.
My attempt was I argued we can always write $Q_{n}....Q_{1}A=R$ with
\begin{array}{c|c} 
  I_{n-1} & 0 \\ 
  \hline 
  O & H_{n} 
\end{array}
is $Q_{n}$ but I could not make progress.

This is a simple index-counting argument. If you have a (general) matrix $A$ with $k$ (non-zero) sub-diagonals and $B$ with $l$ sub-diagonals, then their product $AB$ is either full or has exactly $k+l$ sub-diagonals.
So if $A=QR$ with $R$ having zero sub-diagonals, this implies that $Q$ must have $k$ sub-diagonals, or, in other words, $A$ and $Q$ have the same amount of sub-diagonals.
